# How to speed up the write operation in Databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am ingesting a dataframe from a datasource (df_example), has two columns (col1: string, col2: string)

```
df_example.count()
Out[14]: 116020036

df_example.rdd.getNumPartions()
Out[15]: 20

spark.sparkContext.defaultParallelism
Out[16]: 8

spark.conf.get("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions")
Out[17]: '200'
```

I need to write this dataframe in Azure SQL DB
I am executing the below code its taking very long

```
df_example.write \

.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
.mode("overwrite") \
.option("url", url) \
.option("dbtable", "dbo.example") \
.option("accessToken", access_token) \
.option("encrypt", "true") \
.option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
.option("tableLock", "true") \
.option("reliabilityLevel", "BEST_EFFORT") \
.save()
```

I see 20 tasks for this Job
4.3h have passed  only 1/20 completed
Data written 32.8 MiB/2.3 GiB

Comment: What’s the structure of the SQL table? Heap? Clustered index? Any indexes or constraints?

Comment: increase batchsize parameter

Comment: too many unknowns here - what is the cluster size in databricks, what is the db spec? table definition, indexes etc? what does databricks do before writing via JDBC?

Comment: @Umar.H cluster size is 14GB memory, 4 Cores, 0.75 DBU, databricks fetch this data from datalake and then writes to db via jdbc

Comment: @AnuroopAich could you please suggest any solution. I am in the same boat now. The SQL ingestion from my pyspark notebook is taking  1 to 1.5 hours. My current configuration includes bulkCopyBatchSize 10000, bulkCopyTableLock True and bulkCopyTimeout- 6000000. There are no indexes on my SQL tables at the moment. Please share your experience :-)